# Integrate $\int\tan^2x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \tan^2xdx$

Here is what I tried...

$\int \tan^2xdx = \int (\sec^2x-1)dx = \int(\frac{1}{\cos^2x} -1)dx = \int \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{2} (1+\cos2x)} = \frac{2}{1} \int \frac{1}{1+\cos2x}$

$u = \cos2x, du = 2\sin2xdx$

$= 2 \bigg( \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{2}\sin2x} \bigg) + C$

But the answer is $ \tan x - x + C$.

I think the way that I set up the problem (using half angle identity of $\cos^2x$ in the denominator started making the calculations a lot harder to follow in my opinion) was an issue and that I could have set it up better?

Comment: I think the main point is that you should know that the integral of the $\sec^2$ is equal to $\tan$. You can derive it probably by setting $u=\cos(x)$ and you get something that simplifies. (You should do the substitution directly without simplifying the $\cos^2$)

Comment: There are correct answers below, but you should know that there are things wrong with your answer, that you really should understand. Minor issue (I assume): you lost the $-1$ in the integrand. Major issue (if I understand what you did): $$\int {1\over  \text {something} }\,dx \not= {1 \over \int \text{something}\, dx}.$$

Comment: @peterag yeaaa that's what I did...damn. I can't believe I overlooked derivative of $/tan $ is $\sec^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int(\sec^2x-1)dx=\int\sec^2x\ dx-\int dx=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan{x}\right)=\sec^2{x}\implies \int\sec^2{x}\,dx=\tan{x}+C
$$

$$
\int \tan^2x\,dx = \int(\sec^2x-1)\,dx=
\int\sec^2x\,dx-\int\,dx=\tan{x}-x+C.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $\tan x$ is $1+\tan^2x$. Then
$$\int\tan^2x\,dx = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan x\,\mathrm{d}x-x+c = \tan x -x+c. $$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\tan^2(x)dx=\int\sec^2(x)-1dx$$
as:$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1\to1+\tan^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$
also we know that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\tan(x)\right]=\sec^2(x)$$
so:
$$I=\tan(x)-\int dx=\tan(x)-x+C$$